# Is there any way I set omitempty by default for specific json.Encoder or in fallback on global configuration?

Tags: json, go, yaml, bson, go-structtag

like

```golang
type User struct {
    ID       int32     `json:"_id"` 
    Week     string    `json:"week"`         
}

json.Marshal(&User{},true)//omitempty is true
```

will return

```golang
{}
```

is bson,yaml,sql or any other library support this feature?

Comment: No, but you can use a tool like `github.com/fatih/gomodifytags` to modify the types in your source code easily.

Comment: the thing is that I accept an object, do some processing, and then hand the object to json,there is no way that I can edit the original  struct.

Comment: You can copy the original type and then modify the tags. To guarantee compatibility if the original changes, add a type conversion from the original to your type somewhere.